# Redirect with www on without www

Tags: 7, redirection, .htaccess

I need to do a redirect to the transition from www passed on without www. I uncomment this part in `.htaccess`. But when I go to the website link `www.site.com` I get an error: `This webpage is not available`

```
# To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
# (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
# uncomment the following:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Without www site works.
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

In the firebug displays 3 error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
GET _http://www.example.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Comment: What's in server's error log? For http://www.molot.pl it simply worked, done exactly the same way on stock .htaccess file, so your situation is somehow different - and only you or your admin can see why.

Comment: In the error.log nothing

Comment: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` suggest some non-printable character in name you put in .htaccess, like windows line ending. Or Russian letter that just happen to look like English one, but in fact isn't. Things like that.

Comment: So I'm using the default .htaccess only 2 lines uncommented. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19311/discussion-between-pearson-and-molot).

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Answer (score 0):

Use the following .htaccess rule when user enter in browser `sitename.com` then it will run as www.sitename.com.

Here we write the rewrite rule condition.
For more details please visit following the website:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

```
**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]**
```

Comment: That is the opposite of what the question asks for.